# How to write a background service in Bada?

Tags: bada

How can I write a service running in background for a Bada app? I need to write a service that starts when the device it booted up, and need it to run in background, so that it listens to incoming sms messages, and do some special actions once it recognizes sms with special commands.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible to have a program running in background full time. but user can terminate it using task manager.

I have an idea make an application without any form (like windows console applications) make your SMS listening code in there and try to use conditional launch capability in APPMANAGER class (you should find a condition command match your desire launch condition) and check if it is possible to terminate it or not, if not so it will work else you should find a way to tell the user not to terminate the app .

I hope it works, and let us know your feedback.

yours sincerely

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. The services are part of the Bada OS and not provided by third parties.

You might have some joy using widgets on the home screen to provide one touch access to your functionality.

Reading, [the introduction to Chapter 5 of "Introduction to Bada"](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=services%20%22introduction%20to%20bada%22&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDkQFjAB&url=http://media.wiley.com/assets/2249/10/introduction_to_bada_part_3.pdf&ei=rC7ZTuSfIcmDhQf_7Y3KDg&usg=AFQjCNGEwmBlV8kBhjLbWFpADxPhXiTZYw&cad=rja) identifies that some services can only by *used* by **partner developers**.

This book is likely out of date but I have found nothing to contradict it in my perusal of the Help files packaged with my 2.0.2 SDK.